# How to express this feeling?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I am looking for a phrase to express a feeling.
Here it is.

> A song was out in the market a couple of years ago and it was a huge
>   hit at that time. Today, I heard that song which reminded me all the
>   memories happened in my life at that time. Like it reminded me of my
>   bike ride : I was travelling on bike listening to that song, I was young
>   and funky at that time and my old friends faces. Listening to that song reminds me all of
>   these.

How to express this? Can I say it as that song times? Example: Can I say it as "I was grown up as adult at that song times?" Correct me and please suggest.

Comment: As someone has already answered I believe ***nostalgia*** is the word you are looking for. But I should point out that there are a number of grammatical/idiomatic errors in your OP. If you would like I will edit it for you, but you may benefit from the English Language Learners site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably, the word you're looking for is **[nostalgia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nostalgia)**

> a sentimental longing or wistful affection for a period in the past (Oxford)

*I have quite a few **nostalgic** memories of that song.*

Answer (score 1):

A word that also hints at the triggering of the memory from the song (or some other thing) is [reminiscent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reminiscent)

> - reminding you of someone or something else : similar to something else
> - thinking about the past : having many thoughts of the past

[This article](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2014/08/musical_nostalgia_the_psychology_and_neuroscience_for_song_preference_and.html) talks specifically about music and memories.